# What does '-t' do in mv command? Example below

Tags: pipe, ls, xargs, mv, filter

```
ls -lrt |grep 'Jun 30th' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs mv -t /destinationFolder
```

I'm trying to move files from certain date or pattern or createuser. It doesn't work properly without the `-t` option.

Could someone please enlighten on `xargs -n` and `-t` in move command?

Comment: You should consider using `find` with a suitable time predicate (`-mtime`, `-newerXY` etc.) for this task, rather than parsing the output of `ls -lr`

Comment: what @steeldriver said but more emphatically: [Don't Parse ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: The `-t` option for `mv` is not in the [POSIX standard](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/mv/), and not all versions of `mv` have it — for example, macOS doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `mv` man page

```
   -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
          move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

`mv`'s default behavior is to move everything into the last argument so when `xargs` executes the command it does it like 
    `mv /destinationFolder pipedArgs` without the `-t` it would try to move everything into the last arg piped to xargs. With the `-t` you're explicitly saying to move it HERE.

From the `xargs` man page

```
 -n max-args
      Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s option) is exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.
```

Normally `xargs` will pass all the args at once to the command. For example

```
echo 1 2 3 4 |xargs echo
1 2 3 4
```

executes

```
echo 1 2 3 4
```

While

```
echo 1 2 3 4 |xargs -n 1 echo
```

executes

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
```